# Refactor this if statement using DRY principles

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

Is there a way to write this if statement where "logic" is the same copied logic? I would like to have "logic" and "morelogic" appear only once in the statement.

```
if (a.Exists)
{
  if (b.Exists)
  {
    logic
  }
  else
  {
    morelogic
  }
}
else
{
  logic
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(a.Exists && !b.Exists) 
{
   morelogic
}
else 
{
  logic
}
```